# Проблема взаимной инициализации двух синглтонов

Tags: java, шаблон-одиночка

У меня есть два класса, использующий паттерн `Singleton`:

```
class SingletonA {
    private static final SingletonA mSingletonA = new SingletonA();
    private SingletonB mSingletonB = SingletonB.getInstance();

    public static SingletonA getInstance() {
        return mSingletonA;
    }

    ...
}

class SingletonB {
    private static final SingletonB mSingletonB = new SingletonB();
    private SingletonA mSingletonA = SingletonA.getInstance();

    public static SingletonB getInstance() {
        return mSingletonB;
    }

    ...
}
```

При таком использовании (в проекте аналоги таких классов были немного больше и я не заметил возможность взаимной блокировки), один класс инициализируется, но получает от другого класса в `getInstance()` значение `null`.

---

Как можно решить эту проблему без применения костылей и изменения архитектуры (я уже потопал менять архитектуру, коль уж такое дело, но все же интересно узнать возможные пути решения)?

Comment: @Regent, да. Исправил.

Comment: Добавьте каждому классу по сеттеру соседнего класса. И в статическом блоке задайте эти классы

Comment: По-моему, лучше вообще убрать `private SingletonB mSingletonB = SingletonB.getInstance();` и `private SingletonA mSingletonA = SingletonA.getInstance();` и обращаться к `getInstance` другого класса только при необходимости в методах.

Comment: @Regent, я немного не одобряю такой подход (хотя и были случаи необходимости такого использования). Неявные зависимости ничего хорошего из себя не представляют и только усложняют код. Да и разве Ваш вариант поможет?

Comment: @Victor, тоже интересный подход. Только лучше бы сделать метод `initialize`, где будет вставляться один класс в другой.

Comment: Мы ведь исходим из того, что есть два синглтона и нельзя менять архитектуру? По крайней мере, в вашем вопросе сказано так. При текущем коде в обоих синглтонах в качестве другого синглтона будет `null`. В предлагаемом мною варианте оба синглтона нормально инициализируются без зависимостей друг от друга в конструкторе, после чего ими спокойно можно будет пользоваться в методах.

Comment: @Regent, а... Извиняюсь, я не правильно представил у себя в голове работу с данным вариантом. Сначала у меня возникла мысль, что все равно произойдет стык зависимостей, но нет — все нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментариях были найдены следующие пути решения:

1. Внести в классы метод `setSingletonB(SingletonB singleton)` или `initialize(SingletonB singleton)`, чтобы передать второй класс, после вызова метода `getInstance()`.
2. Сделать так, чтобы был единственный `Singleton`, который содержит в себе другой класс (суть не изменится, один экземпляр будет работать исключительно с одним экземпляром), если есть такая возможность.
3. Убрать `SingletonB mSingletonB` и `SingletonA mSingletonA`, а обращаться к ним напрямую из методом.